# getTime() not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have following javascript code which works fine in IE and firefox

```
var dt = new Date("17/05/2012 05:22:02").getTime();
```

but in chrome the value of the dt is NaN.
I am not able to find what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems to be a known issue with dd/mm format in both Safari as well as Chrome -
 http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=5704

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
var dt = new Date("05/17/2012 05:22:02").getTime()
```

I would suggest using unixtimestamp for dates as each browser treats them differently or use http://www.datejs.com/ library